# autoconf installation in solaris 9

Tags: installation, solaris, build, autoconf

```
bash-2.05$ ./autogen.sh
buildcheck: checking installation...
./build/buildcheck.sh: autoconf: not found
buildcheck: autoconf not found.
            You need autoconf version 2.50 or newer installed.
```

Getting above error while running the script, seem autoconf is not installed, Please help me out with installation process for solaris 9.

Answer (score 1):

Solaris 9 is a very old version, from 2002, and not well supported now that it's years past the end of its support life.  You might find pre-built packages if you search sites like http://unixpackages.com/, but you might be stuck downloading the autoconf source from https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/ and building it yourself.

Comment: *and building it yourself*  **If** it builds - Solaris 9 is waaay old, and Linux-targeted code such as `autoconf` likely won't build without significant modification.  It's literally worse than asking current Windows code to compile on Windows 95.